# Padding offsets height with ng-hide CSS transition

Tags: css, angularjs, css-transitions, padding, ng-animate

I have a problem with CSS transition of heights property when the element has padding on it.

```
.content {
  padding: 10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all linear 1s;
  transition: all linear 1s;
  height: 16px;
}

.content.ng-hide-add { height: 16px; }
.content.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active { height: 0px; }
.content.ng-hide-remove { height: 0px; }
.content.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active { height: 16px; }
```

This is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/pByaUhT8w6ZvzKTr7etR?p=preview

As you can see, the animation still covers 16px, but it was offset by the total of 20px of padding. If you change the padding to 0, the animation works as expected like in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/50zfNnaoOpX7hgl2trYi?p=preview

I tried using `box-sizing:border-box` but that breaks the animation. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1) Change padding-top in animation (text will change its position)

```
.content.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active { height: 0px; padding: 0px 10px;}
.content.ng-hide-remove { height: 0px; padding: 0px 10px;}
```

2) Put your content into container:

HTML:

```
<div ng-hide="!show" class="container">
  <div class="content">Look at my lovely content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  border:1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all linear 1s;
  transition: all linear 1s;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
}

.container.ng-hide-add { height: 38px;}
.container.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active { height: 0px; }
.container.ng-hide-remove { height: 0px; }
.container.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active { height: 38px; }
```

38px = text + padding + border